# How to check password with String in Android

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

For my application login I want use this library : https://github.com/alphamu/PinEntryEditText

In this library for check password use below method :

```
final PinEntryEditText pinEntry = (PinEntryEditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_pin_entry);
if (pinEntry != null) {
    pinEntry.setOnPinEnteredListener(new PinEntryEditText.OnPinEnteredListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPinEntered(CharSequence str) {
            if (str.toString().equals("1234")) {
                Toast.makeText(AnimatedEditTextWidgetsActivity.this, "SUCCESS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(AnimatedEditTextWidgetsActivity.this, "FAIL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                pinEntry.setText(null);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**Check with String constructor :**

```
 public void onPinEntered(CharSequence str) { ... }
```

But my query for check password this :

```
public Boolean login(String password, SQLiteDatabase db) throws SQLException {

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + UserContract.NewUserInfo.TABLE_NAME +
            " WHERE " + UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_PASSWORD + "=?", new String[]{password});

    if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

How can I check password from `SQLite` with **CharSequence str** in above library ?! 
Please edit my code, because I am amateur and I really need this tutorial. Thanks all <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `String` implements `CharSequence` you can use a `String` anywhere you need `CharSequence` -- to get a `String` from a `CharSequence` use `toString()`:

```
 public void onPinEntered(CharSequence str) {
     if( login( str.toString() ) {
         Toast.makeText(AnimatedEditTextWidgetsActivity.this, "SUCCESS",    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     } else {
         Toast.makeText(AnimatedEditTextWidgetsActivity.this, "FAIL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         pinEntry.setText(null);
     }
}
```

Tips:

- Use `boolean` instead of `Boolean` if you don't need a nullable result.
- You generally don't want to do heavy lifting on the UI thread. You'll probably get away with running a quick sqlite query, but your UI will become unresponsive if you do longer operations.